# Hibernate Criteria query on properties of subclasses

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, criteria

Suppose I have:

```
abstract class Shape { boolean visible; }

class Circle extends Shape { int radius; }

class Square extends Shape { int side; }
```

Suppose I want all Shapes with `visible=true`, plus all Circles with `radius=10`, plus all Squares with `side=15`.

I can't do this:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(A.class)
    .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
       .add(Restrictions.eq("visible", true))
       .add(Restrictions.eq("radius", 10))
       .add(Restrictions.eq("side", 15))).list();
```

Because `radius` and `side` are not `Shape` fields:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: radius of: Shape
```

**My question is:** How can I solve this, in a single query, preferably without using HQL?

**Also:** Would Shape's `InheritanceType` (`TABLE_PER_CLASS`, `JOINED`, or `SINGLE_TABLE`) make any difference to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend going with the `InheritanceType.JOINED` as it both models your data well (in both the database and object sides (for instance Square doesn't have a radius in either the database or object model) while allowing you to perform polymorphic queries (in this case searching on `visible` across all Shapes).

The query on a `JOINED` style becomes a bit more difficult as you need to perform a sub-select.  Honestly, it's not that difficult though:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Shape.class)
    .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
       .add(Restrictions.eq("visible", true))
       .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", 
           DetachedCriteria.forClass(Circle.class)
               .add(Restrictions.eq("radius", 10))
               .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("id")))
       .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", 
           DetachedCriteria.forClass(Square.class)
               .add(Restrictions.eq("side", 15))
               .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("id")))))
    ).list();
```

Comment: `Subqueries.propertyIn("id",...` does what? What is the `"id"` propertyName for? Is this the name of the field marked as `@Id`? Sorry to ask that, but I know nothing about Subqueries and never used them before.

Comment: "id" is a property of Shape, which is "in"-ed with the sub-query's results... a little like this: select * from Shape s where s.id in (select id from Square q where q.side = 15)

Comment: Ok, I see you added a `.setProjection` line and now it works. However, I have tested with `InheritanceType.JOINED`, `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` and `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`, and they all work. Was that supposed to happen?

Comment: Yes, they all should work.  I guess I misled you with the wording.  The difference will be the database table structure behind it.  Review the docs for the specifics.